# Как на C# создать браузер, работающий с уведомлениями?

Tags: c#, webbrowser, push-уведомления

Необходимо создать браузер на c#, сделать возможность авторизации и когда сервер будет слать уведомления- как-то их отлавливать и реагировать дальше на основании их данных.
Как такое можно сделать?

Comment: Подобно хрому или другому существующему, или что-то совсем особенное?

Comment: Вам нужно самописный Active-X/COM (или ваш скрипт-совместимый) обьект `Notification`  добавить в скрипт-обработчик браузера. (Вы можете использовать системный ScriptControl, а может у вас самописный обьект JavaScript). Почитав Notification API реализовать функции этого раздела в даном обьекте.

Comment: А сервер - это что? Тоже самописная программа или сторонний сервис? Если и клиент, и сервис пишется самостоятельно, то можно взять WCF, например.